# Com.Parameters.AddWithValue Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

i seem to have an unknown error saying "There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter of 'value' of SqlParamaterCollection.AddWithValue(string, object)

```
//querystring - http://url/ThankYou_form.aspx?email=JakeLoh@gmail.com&password=hello123
//extract info from textbox and save into keywork "CustEmail"
string queryString = "?CustEmail=" + tb_email.Text + "&" + "Custpassword=" + tb_password.Text + "&" + "Custsecurityquestion=" + tb_securityquestion.Text + "&" + "Custage=" + tb_age.Text + "&" + "Custgender=" + tb_gender.Text + "&" + "Custstreet=" + tb_street.Text + "&" + "Custpostal=" + tb_street.Text

//Forward request to ThankYou.aspx
Response.Redirect("ThankYou_Form.aspx" + queryString);

//send data into database
```

Comment: There is lot more details you need to share for the question to be understandable. How are you executing the query? How are you adding parameters to the command? At first glance your query doesn't have any parameters. Which line of code gives you error?

Comment: Did you debug and check what exact value is set to querystring variable? Are you able to run that query directly on the database from management studio?

Comment: Storing a password in a query string is right up there with the worst of possible ideas.